# Migrate Legacy Newsletter to Marketing Campaign

Tags: sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

As we are going to upgrade legacy newsletter to marketing campaign. Please clarify some doubts

We are using JSON call to add/delete particular email in unsubscribe list as below

https://api.sendgrid.com/api/unsubscribes.add.json

HttpWebRequest WebRequestObject = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(Url);

Since request posted through HttpWebRequest, is the migration will affect this code to add/delete email in global suppression list?

As marketing campaign support group suppression, we are not needed that one now. 
Need to add email in global suppression only.

Thanks,

Rahini. K

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The APIv2 calls that you use to add addresses in the Global Suppression list will not be affected by the Legacy Newsletter retirement. Those calls will continue to work as expected.

The Marketing Campaigns app can only use unsubscribe groups at the moment, or a custom link that you can set up on your side, and make it use the above mentioned APIv2 call to add the unsubscribed address to the Global Unsubscribes list.